# How to get data from data table using php

Tags: html, sql, sql-server

i am learning php nad html and mssql

Hello i dont know anything wrong can someone explain me? 
+(everything configured righ in db i guess)

```
<?php
include('Database\DBconnect.php');
?><?php
$procs = "{call p_bas_sel_DataTest()}";   
$paramss = array();
 while($getquestionsfromphp=sqlsrv_fetch_object($results)){ ?>
```

Now HTML

```
<label class="questlabel">1.blah blah?</label>
<div class="answers" id="ans1" style="margin-left: 2em">
<button ><label ><span ><?php echo $getquestionsfromphp['D_Value'];?></span></label></button>
</div><?php } ?>
```

Comment: well what specifically is the problem? As far as I can see from your code you never actually execute your procedure, so that might be a good place to start.

Comment: Also, just a remark, `?><?php` is completely redundant.

Comment: @ADyson Thank you i looked your comment. After that i analyzed code source and i fixed it thank you helped me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<?php
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM Data_Test WHERE lang='M'" ;
    $query = sqlsrv_query ($conn,$sql);
     $arr = array();
     while ($row = sqlsrv_fetch_array($query)){
         $array[] = $row;

        }
?>
```

I fixed my error coding like this i put data into array from database then used on some text as index numbers